# Accessing edges in a graph satisfying some condition in networkx package

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph G with say 100 nodes labeled 1 through to 100.

The graph G is a tournament graph, meaning there is a directed edge between every two nodes in exactly one of either direction.

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)

Now i somehow need to access all edges satisfying the following condition:
(Maybe store them in a list ?) Denote set A={1,2,3,..50}

a) Edges in G between nodes x and y where x,y are in A

b) Any edge in G of the
   form x--->z where x is in A, z is NOT in A

c) Any edge in G of the
   form z--->x where x is in A, z is NOT in A

Essentially I want the union of a) , b) and c).

I am new to python and unable to figure this out cleanly. I am using the networkx package and my graph G is a digraph. (`G=nx.DiGraph()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

```
G.subgraph(A).edges()
```

b)

```
[(i,j) for i,j in G.edges() if i in A and j not in A]
```

c)

```
[(i,j) for i,j in G.edges() if i not in A and j in A]
```

If you want their union, try the following:

```
G.edges()-G.subgraph(G.nodes()-A).edges()
```